# S3-read : process file in secure manner

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3

I have a use case where S3 file acts as input for batch application (written in java), and the file size has reached upto 10 GB.

Currently this S3 file is persisted locally and then worked upon. The problem with this approach is file contains customer data, so it is no secure in local file system ( basically it's not adhering to encryption at rest security rule).

We have searched multiple approaches

1. disk encryption : it might potentially slow down entire batching processing as it generates temp files. POC is in progress.
2. Stream batch input files line by line and do in-memory processing: will make lot of network calls, and will slow down application
3. encrypt customer fields in input files : not feasible as files are sometimes manually created.

Can have a tool to encrypt manually created file but then it cannot scaled to all the clients, requires change in SOP.

Are there any other secure way of processing sizeable red data files which are coming from S3 ?

Comment: I would go for option 1. For option 2 Kinesis might be an option, but I'm not quite sure haven't used it before. Option 3 sounds like a dirty hack. If the encryption might be an issue, you can tune the encryption process with Compute optimized instances.

Comment: What do you mean by "locally"? Is this a computer in your own location, or an Amazon EC2 instance? (If it is not on EC2, would you consider moving your processing to EC2?)

Comment: @John Rotenstein yes locally === EC2 host of application.

Comment: AWS Athena would be another option to securely process large files from S3

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EBS volumes can be encrypted, which means the data is **encrypted at rest**. It does *not* slow down disk access and it is transparent to the operation of the Amazon EC2 instance.

See: [Amazon EBS Encryption - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSEncryption.html)

You should then **ensure that minimal people have the ability to login to the EC2 instance**. If they can login, then they can read the local files and, most probably, use the assigned IAM role to read the source data from Amazon S3.

Also, **review your IAM permissions** because anybody with permission to take snapshots/AMIs of EBS volumes could copy their contents to access the data. The best advice is to only give people the access necessary for their role, and nothing more.